# getting json data from POST

Tags: jquery

console.log(data) gives the following results

```
{
    "ERRORS": [
        {
            "MESSAGE": "Error on API.",
            "CODE": "hermes05"
        }
    ],
    "DATA": {}
}
```

When I try to get the value message out I get undefined, why?

```
error: function(data){

  console.log(data.ERRORS[0].MESSAGE);

}
```

FULL CODE

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "http://api.domain.com/something",
                data: {
                    // Send value in mobile input field.
                    mobile:  $("#mobileNo").val()
                },

                success: function(data){

                },

        error: function(data){

             console.log(data.ERRORS.MESSAGE);

                }
            });


            // stop button from submitting.
            event.preventDefault(); // cancel default behavior
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure `data` is parsed as JSON?

Comment: yep type: "POST", dataType: "json",  url: "http://domain.com",

Comment: full code i'm using above updated

Comment: @Spike well there is your error... In your full code you are **not** doing the same thing as your sample code....

Comment: @Neal I have tried both data.ERRORS.MESSAGE and data.ERRORS[1].MESSAGE with no joy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is

```
error: function(jqXhr) {
  try {
    data = JSON.parse(jqXhr.responseText);
    console.log(data.ERRORS[0].MESSAGE);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Response was not valid JSON");
  }
}
```

Check out the difference between `success` and `error` at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

This is because `error` callback has `jqXHR`, `textStatus`, `errorThrown` parameters - you have to refer to `jqXHR.responseText` - see [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: I don't think `jqXHR` has a `data` property. I just tested it out and got `undefined`. I think in this case the JSON must be parsed from the `responseText`.

Comment: Yes my bad, property is `responseText` and should be parsed as json to be interpreted.